# How do I add sound effects to an iPad app

Tags: ipad, audio

I need a library that helps me manipulate a sound file playing in a custom app on an iPad.
Here's what I mean.

Users runs app.

User play track.

User presses a button and an echo occurs.

User presses a button and the music loops.

And other similar DJ events....

Is there an API that makes this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and if your sounds are short enough AudioToolbox.framework. should be enough, if not: AVFoundation.framework CoreAudio.framework